# How do I access an instance variable inside a BindingAdapter when using Android Data Binding?

Tags: android, static-methods, android-databinding

So I'm using this popular data binding code snippet to load in image into imageview of list items by passing in URL:

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp""
        app:imageUrl="@{movie.imageUrl}"
        />
```

The Binding Adapter:

```
class Movie{
    boolean isLoaded;

    @BindingAdapter({"bind:imageUrl"})
        public static void loadImage(final ImageView view, String imageUrl) {

            Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(view, new Callback.EmptyCallback() {
                @Override public void onSuccess() {
                    //set isLoaded to true for the listview item
                    // but cannot access boolean isLoaded as it is non static.
                });
    }
```

If I simply make the `BindingAdapter` non-static then it throws error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null     in class MovieTileBinding. A BindingAdapter in     com.example.moviesapp.Pojos.Results is not static and requires an object to     use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.
```

Comment: This great blogpost will show u how to use non-static BindingAdapter https://realm.io/news/data-binding-android-boyar-mount/.

Comment: Check out the solution from this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38216344/1650674

Answer (score 1):

Put whole movie instace through custom biding adapter:

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp""
        app:movie="@{movie}"
        />
```

The Binding Adapter:

```
class Movie{
boolean isLoaded;

@BindingAdapter({"movie"})
    public static void loadImage(final ImageView view, final Movie movie) {
        if(movie != null && moview.getImageUrl() != null){
          Picasso.with(view.getContext())
             .load(movie.getImageUrl())
             .into(view, new Callback.EmptyCallback() {
             @Override public void onSuccess() {
                 image.setLoaded(true);
             });
     }
}
```