# How to setup a @BindingAdapter with Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso, android-databinding

I would like to create a gridview of movie posters images with using bindings.

My viewmodel looks like that:

```
public class PopularMoviesViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    Movie movie;
    Context context;

    MovieServiceComponent movieServiceComponent = DaggerMovieServiceComponent.builder()
            .contextModule(new ContextModule(context))
            .build();

    Picasso getPicasso = movieServiceComponent.getPicasso();

    public PopularMoviesViewModel(Movie movie, Context context) {
        this.movie = movie;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getImageUrl(){
        return movie.posterPath();
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getTitle(){
        return movie.originalTitle();
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})
    public void setImageUrl(ImageView view, String poserPath){
        getPicasso.with(view.getContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+ poserPath).into(view);

    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data class="PopularMoviesBinding">
    <variable
        name="pmvm"
        type="com.hartyandi.oviesm.modelviews.PopularMoviesViewModel"></variable>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout


        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="2.5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            app:imageUrl="@{pmvm.imageUrl}"
            android:id="@+id/popular_movies_grid_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:elevation="20dp">

        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popular_movies_grid_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{pmvm.title}"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Adapter:

```
public class PopularMoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularMoviesAdapter.BindingHolder> {

    private List<Movie> movies;
    private Context context;

    public PopularMoviesAdapter(List<Movie> movies, Context context) {
        this.movies = movies;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void add(Movie movie){
        movies.add(movie);
    }

    @Override
    public BindingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        PopularMoviesBinding popularMoviesBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.popular_movies_gridview_row, parent,false);
        return new BindingHolder(popularMoviesBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PopularMoviesAdapter.BindingHolder holder, int position) {
        PopularMoviesBinding popularMoviesBinding = holder.popularMoviesBinding;
        popularMoviesBinding.setPmvm(new PopularMoviesViewModel(movies.get(position), context));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }

    public class BindingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private PopularMoviesBinding popularMoviesBinding;

        public BindingHolder(PopularMoviesBinding popularMoviesBinding) {
            super(popularMoviesBinding.getRoot());
            this.popularMoviesBinding = popularMoviesBinding;
        }
 }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null in class PopularMoviesBinding.A BindingAdapter in modelviews.PopularMoviesViewModel is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent.
```

[I tried to change my implementation just like this stackoverflow post suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904519/how-do-i-change-an-observable-field-from-inside-a-bindingadapter-in-android-data) and I got the same error message.

[I also used the following code as example.](https://barta.me/android-mvvm-pattern/)

Could someone explain what the problem with the code, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably didn't intend to use an instance method for the `BindingAdapter`.

If you do, you must provide a [DataBindingComponent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.html) so that the generated Binding class knows which instance to use.

You have two options -- provide a `DataBindingComponent` or just pass the required context as an attribute to a static binding adapter method. The second is a bit easier to understand, so I'll start with that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data class="PopularMoviesBinding">
        <variable name="pmvm"
            type="com.hartyandi.oviesm.modelviews.PopularMoviesViewModel"/>
        <variable name="picasso" type="com.whatever.Picasso"/>
    </data>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ImageView
        app:imageUrl="@{pmvm.imageUrl}"
        app:picasso="@{picasso}"
        ... />
    </ImageView>
</layout>
```

Then in your BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl", "picasso"})
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView view, String poserPath, Picasso picasso){
    picasso.with(view.getContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+ poserPath).into(view);
}
```

Note that setImageUrl is now `static`.

Alternatively, since your the Picasso instance is also on the ViewModel, you can just pass the instance by adding a getter for the picasso:

```
<ImageView
    app:imageUrl="@{pmvm.imageUrl}"
    app:picasso="@{pmvm.picasso}"
    ... />
```

and the method in your ViewModel:

```
public Picasso getPicasso() { return this.getPicasso; }
```

The other way means that you implement a `DataBindingComponent`. When you create an instance BindingAdapter method, the generated interface will have a getter for your class. You'll need to create a class to implement that interface:

```
public class MyDataBindingComponent implements DataBindingComponent {
    public PopularMoviesViewModel getPopularMoviesViewModel() {
         return whateverIDoToCreateOrGetThisBindingAdapterInstance();
    }
}
```

Then you pass the instance when you inflate or bind:

```
PopularMoviesBinding popularMoviesBinding = 
    DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
        R.layout.popular_movies_gridview_row, parent,false,
        new MyDataBindingComponent());
```

Answer (score 1):

just make the *setImageUrl()* method *static* to be like this code

```
@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})
public void setImageUrl(ImageView view, String poserPath){
    getPicasso.with(view.getContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185"+ 
    poserPath).into(view);

}
```