# Image url on ImageView by using data binding with Picasso in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my project I need to import images from for example:

```
example.com/cars/images/...image.png
example.com/cars/images/...image2.png
example.com/cars/images/...image3.png
```

image extension changes according to name from api.

I need to show images one by one in imageview(RecyclerView).

How can I do this using data binding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup a @BindingAdapter with Picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838167/how-to-setup-a-bindingadapter-with-picasso)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class or file for your load image function, ex "Image loading".

Then you will create your function there

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun loadImage(view: View, 
imageUrl: String?) {
val image: ImageView = view as ImageView
Glide.with(image.context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(image)
}
```

Note: this example using Glide, you can replace it with Picasso as you need, but the idea is the same.

After that call your function in your Imageview.

```
app:imageUrl="@{imagesModel.imageUrl}"
```

I will give you all the xml file that you can be familiar with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout 

<data>

    <variable
        name="imagesModel"
        type="com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.data.model.image.Images" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_120sdp"
        android:background="@color/card_color"
        android:padding="1.5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:imageUrl="@{imagesModel.imageUrl}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/hd_shadow_overlay_gradient_large_transparent_png_image_" />
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

And that's it. Will working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the end of the url will actually change like this example.com/cars/$urlName
I'm getting the urlName from a database.